# Definition of $\underline{\int_{a}^{b}} f(x) \,dx$ and $\overline{\int_{a}^{b}} f(x) \,dx$ unclear

Tags: analysis, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I don't quite understand the definition of $\underline{\int_{a}^{b}} f(x) \,dx$ and   $\overline{\int_{a}^{b}} f(x) \,dx$. Should I interpret $\underline{\int_{a}^{b}} f(x) \,dx$ as the largest area that is part of a lower sum and $\overline{\int_{a}^{b}} f(x) \,dx$ as the smallest area that is part of the upper sum,
but then this no longer seems logical to me (*):
\begin{align} 
\underline{S}(f,V)\leq \underline{\int_{a}^{b}} f(x) \,dx \leq \overline{\int_{a}^{b}} f(x) \,dx \leq \overline{S}(f,V)
\end{align}
where $V=\{a=x_0<x_1<...<x_n=b\}$ a partition of the interval $[a,b]$ and $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$.
The largest area that is part of a lower sum is not greater than or equal to the entire lower sum, right? Can someone help me with the definitions of $\underline{\int_{a}^{b}} f(x) \,dx$ and $\overline{\int_{a}^{b}} f(x) \,dx$?

$\underline{S}(f,V)$ is the lower sum, $\overline{S}(f,V)$ is the upper sum, $\underline{\int_{a}^{b}} f(x) \,dx$ is the lower integral and $\overline{\int_{a}^{b}} f(x) \,dx$ is the upper integral.

Comment: What definitions do you have for these symbols?

Comment: what is $\underline{S}(f,V)$? Anyway, we define $\underline{\int_a^b}f$ to be the supremum of all Darboux lower sums $L(f,P)$ of $f$, where $P$ is a partition of $[a,b]$. Similarly, $\overline{\int_a^b}f$ is defined as the infimum of all upper sums $U(f,P)$ of $f$, where $P$ is a partition of $[a,b]$. See the Wikipedia page [Darboux Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral).

Comment: Also, from which book are you studying from? If you edit your post to include these details, then your question will be much better received. Please provide [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960).

Comment: I use the book written by one of my professors

Comment: @Sam: Does peek-a-boo's comment clarify things for you?

Comment: @Joe it's still not clear to me why (*) holds. (I edited this in my post)

Comment: the first and last inequality hold by definition of supremum and infimum. To establish the middle inequality, one first proves a lemma: for any partition $P,P'$ of $[a,b]$, we have $L(f,P)\leq U(f,P')$. This is because $L(f,P)\leq L(f,P\cup P')\leq U(f,P\cup P')\leq U(f,P')$ (surely whatever textbook you're following must have stated something to this effect). If this is still not clear, or it's not mentioned in your textbook, I'd highly suggest you read chapter 13 in Spivak's Calculus.

Comment: @peek-a-boo does this apply to all functions or only to monotonously increasing functions?

Comment: all bounded functions (so that the lower and upper sums are defined in $\Bbb{R}$). Monotonicity is not required.

Comment: @Sam: I also recommend Spivak. He gives far better exposition than anyone on Stack Exchange has the capacity to.